# In a text that part of the characters are in Hebrew, how to delete spaces before and after a comma using regex?

Tags: awk, sed

I need to remove the spaces that are before and after the commas in a csv file that contains Hebrew characters. The solution to this problem would be quite simple when the csv file contains only English characters using sed and regex. But in my case, I can't get the desired result because of the Hebrew characters.

example of a line in the csv file:
`file1, file2, קובץ 3, קובץ 4, קובץ 5, סוף`

this command works only when all characters are in english: `sed 's/(\s+,)?(,\s+)?/,/' -i file_path`

Comment: Does `sed -i -E 's/[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*/,/g' file` or `sed -i -E 's/\s*,\s*/,/g' file` work?

Comment: `sed 's/(\s+,)?(,\s+)?/,/'` will not work because you haven't used `-E` option (and even with `-E` the logic isn't correct), also try `sed 's/\s*,\s*/,/'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*/,/g' file > otufile
sed -i 's/\s*,\s*/,/g' file
```

See [online demo](https://ideone.com/a5mc3G)

**Details**

- `[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*` - any 0 or more whitespace, comma,  any 0 or more whitespace
- `g` - global flag, matches and replaces all occurrences in the string.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribizew. Actually I don't think I explained myself well in the question... Because in the CSV, sometimes one space appears before the comma, sometimes two after the comma, etc. The text is not regular. I tested the `sed` that I wrote in the question on [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) and it works only with all English characters but not when there is characters in Hebrew

Comment: @D.N. I see, but regexr is only supporting PCRE/JavaScript regexps. `sed` is a POSIX tool. `\s` / `[[:space:]]` matches any whitespace, it does not care if there are any other chars around, letters, digits, punctuation.